# Only Django Admin pages visible while rest of Site blank in production

Tags: python, django, heroku-cli

Im trying to host my site on heroku on my localhost my project is fine with no issues , on deploying it all I get are blank pages (I inspected it and elements are shown but nothing is visible on webpage)apart from admin pages I installed all the necessary packages as I was deploying that is to say gunicorn and whitenoise as well as setting STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_STORAGE . I at first set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 1 and later set it to 0 when deploying, I have failed to see any error that might be causing the issue

some of my files for context

settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dev')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import handler404


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('user.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('store/', include('store.urls')),
    #path("djangorave/", include("djangorave.urls", namespace="djangorave")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


#error handlers
handler404 = 'store.views.error_404'
#handler500 = 'store.views.my_custom_error_view'
```

Comment: Does the blank page have status code 200? Have you set [settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) properly? Can you set `settings.DEBUG` to `True` if it will show any error?

Comment: my     ```  ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ ' * '  ] ``` and yes Debug is True and i am getting 200 ok  but from more inspection my heroku app seems not to find a specific JS file yet the path to it is correct @yedpodtrzitko